# Understanding the function $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$, where $f$ is a complex analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Here's the specific question I'm looking at.

$D$ is the open half disc $D=\{z=x+iy: |z-2| < 6, x>2\}$. $f$ is analytic on some open set containing $\overline{D}$, and has no zeros on the boundary of $D$.

We further assume that $\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\partial D}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz =2$, $\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\partial D}\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)}dz =6$, $\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\partial D}\frac{z^2f'(z)}{f(z)}dz =14$.

Find all solutions to $f(z) = 0$ in D.

I'm not necessarily looking for a solution to the problem at this point. Right now I'm just hoping to get some insight on what exactly $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$ is, and how the above integration assumptions can be used to understand the zeros of $f$ on $D$.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Haven't tried it myself but I think this is the way to go: If $a_1,\cdots,a_k$ are the zeros of $f$ in $D$, write $f=(x-a_1)\cdots(x-a_k)g(x)$ where $g(x)$ is analytic with no zero in $D$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since 
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\partial D}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz =2$$
we know that $f(z)$ has two zeros $a$ and $b$ in $D$. Let
$$ f(z)=(z-a)(z-b)g(z)$$
where $g(z)\neq0$ in $\overline{D}$. Then
$$ \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}=\frac{1}{z-a}+\frac1{z-b}+\frac{g'(z)}{g(z)} $$
Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\partial D}\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)}dz\\
&=&\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\partial D}\bigg[\frac{z}{z-a}+\frac{z}{z-b}+\frac{zg'(z)}{g(z)}\bigg]dz\\
&=&a+b.
\end{eqnarray*}
Similarly
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\partial D}\frac{z^2f'(z)}{f(z)}dz =a^2+b^2. $$
So
$$ a+b=6,a^2+b^2=14 $$
from which we have
$$ a=3-i \sqrt{2},b= 3+i \sqrt{2},\text{ or }a= 3+i \sqrt{2},b= 3-i \sqrt{2}.$$
So $f(z)=0$ has two solutions $z=3\pm i \sqrt{2}$.