# Find the zeros of $f$ inside $C$ given the values of $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{z^n f'(z)}{f(z)} \, dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be analytic in $|z|<2$ and $C=\{|z|=1\}$. If $f$ does not have zeros at $C$ and

\begin{gather*}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} \, dz = 2, \\
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)} \, dz =0, \\
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{z^2f'(z)}{f(z)} \, dz = \frac{1}{2},
\end{gather*}

find the zeros inside $C$.

I was thinking Argument Principle but I am not sure. Any help?

Comment: Surely, since $C=\{\|z\|=1\}$ is a closed curve (the unit circle), the Cauchy Integral Theorem shows that all of these integrals must be zero, unless $f’(z)/f(z)$ isn’t holomorphic

Comment: You should find how many zeros are inside the contour, not where they are, shouldn't you?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3642123/42969 for a similar question. The same approach works here.